# Do AsyncIO stream writers/readers require manually ensuring that all data is sent/received?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

When dealing with sockets, you need to make sure that all data is sent/received, since you may receive incomplete chunks of data when reading. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket):

> In general, they return when the associated network buffers have been filled (send) or emptied (recv). They then tell you how many bytes they handled. **It is your responsibility to call them again until your message has been completely dealt with**.

Emphasis mine. It then shows sample implementations that ensure all data has been handled in each direction.

---

Is the same true though when dealing with AsyncIO wrappers over sockets?

For [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=write#asyncio.StreamReader.read), it seems to be required as the docs mention that it "[reads] **up to** n bytes.".

For [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=write#asyncio.StreamWriter.write) though, it seems like as long as you call `drain` afterwards, you know that it's all sent. The docs don't explicitly say that it must be called repeatedly, and `write` doesn't return anything.

Is this correct? Do I need to check how much was read using `read`, but can just `drain` the `StreamWriter` and know that everything was sent?

I thought that my above assumptions were correct, then I had a look at the [example TCP Client](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=write#tcp-echo-client-using-streams) immediately below the method docs:

```
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()

asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client('Hello World!'))
```

And it doesn't do any kind of checking. It assumes everything is both read and written the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For `read`, [checking for incomplete read] seems to be required as the docs mention that it "[reads] up to n bytes.".

Correct, and this is a useful feature for many kinds of processing, as it allows you to read new data as it arrives from the peer and process it incrementally, without having to know how much to expect at any point. If you do know exactly how much you expect and need to read that amount of bytes, you can use [`readexactly`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=write#asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly).

> For `write` though, it seems like as long as you call drain afterwards, you know that it's all sent. The docs don't explicitly say that it must be called repeatedly, and write doesn't return anything.

This is partially correct. Yes, asyncio will automatically keep writing the data you give it in the background until all is written, so you don't need to (nor can you) ensure it by checking the return value of `write`.

However, a sequence of `stream.write(data); await stream.drain()` will not pause the coroutine until all data has been transmitted to the OS. This is because `drain` doesn't wait for *all* data to be written, it only waits until it hits a "low watermark", trying to ensure (misguidedly [according to some](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#bug-3-closing-time)) that the buffer never becomes empty as long as there are new writes. As far as I know, in current asyncio there is **no way** to wait until all data has been sent - except for manually tweaking the watermarks, which is inconvenient and which the documentation warns against.

This is not as bad as it sounds simply because a successful `write` itself doesn't guarantee that the data was actually transmitted to, let alone received by the peer - it could be languishing in the socket buffer, or in network equipment along the way. But as long as you can rely on the system to send out the data you gave it as fast as possible, you don't really care whether some of it is in an asyncio buffer or in a kernel buffer. (But you still need to await `drain()` to ensure [backpressure](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#bug-1-backpressure).)

The one time you *do* care is when you are about to exit the program or the event loop; in that case, a portion of the data being stuck in an asyncio buffer means that the peer will *never* see it. This is why, starting with 3.7, asyncio provides a `wait_closed()` method which you can await after calling `close()` to ensure that all the data has been sent. One could imagine a `flush()` method that does the same, but without having to actually close the socket (analogous to the method of the same name on `file` objects, and with equivalent semantics), but currently there are no plans to add it.

Comment: So I notice that without `wait_closed`, there is no guarantee it is sent? How can I not close the socket and guarantee such a thing? I notice when I `drain()`, it does not guarantee. (only if the server itself exits otherwise, then will it flush). For example, imagine a situation you want a few messages exchanged with a client ... but currently this is not possible.

Comment: @user129393192 When I was researching this response, there was no way to wait until all the data got written, except perhaps by changing the watermark values. However, the answer makes the case (in the paragraph beginning with "this is not as bad as it sounds") that you shouldn't _care_, because the fact even `write(2)` getting invoked doesn't mean that the data was delivered to the peer - just that it got moved from a userspace buffer to a kernel one. Messages sent via `stream.write(data)` _will_ get sent eventually without explicit action on your side, and that's all you should care about.

Comment: So does this imply that the `wait_closed` is not necessary if you don't end up using `write` at all?

Comment: @user129393192 Yes. You need to use `wait_closed()` if: you've written to the socket, **and** the program exits before waiting for some sort of response from the peer.